# Sprocket: Assets are not loading

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Rails is not loading my assets, I have precompiled the assets million of times but all in vain. Not a single CSS or JS file get loaded. Even firebug says, `jquery is undefined`.

```
Rails -v = 3.2.2
Sprocket -v = 2.1.2
jquery-rails -v = 3.1
```

I have set `config.assets.compile = true` and `config.assets.debug = true` in development.rb.

Moreoever I have also gone through all the SO link.

Please help, I know its noobbish but I have been stucked here from last 2 days. I am even reinstalled each thing but still all in vain

Please Help!

Comment: I think config.assets.debug = true should be false in development env. Better test directly with a production env. You obviously need to precompile assets for production [```RAILS_ENV=precompile bundle exec rake assets:precompile```] then run a production server [ ```RAILS_ENV=production rails s ```]. Then we can check maybe it's something wrong with your pipeline ;)

Comment: ```config.assets.debug = false``` is what make sprockets concatenate all the files.

Comment: all in vain :( nothing happens :( I dont know how it was working fine before.... but it still not loading the assets even it compiled the assets successfully but none of the assets load in browser

Comment: can you show the CSS and JS manifest file contents?

Comment: share your `application.js` and check in `application.rb` file `config.assets.digest = true` there or not.

Comment: @Kingston my application.js and application.css are empty, when i view them from browser, but I have all my code compiled in them.

Comment: share your `application.js`.

Comment: have you checked config/application.rb whether it has `require "sprockets/railtie"` or `require 'rails/all'`